# Why same connection code to PostgreSQL by OleDB provider, in a different projects, sometimes failed?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, oledb, oledbconnection

I created some code for connection to PostgreSQL database, by using OleDB provider.

This is my code

```
string connectionString = "Provider=PostgreSQL;Data             
Source=localhost;location=vb_main;User ID=postgres;password=somepassword;";

var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
```

In some project this code is working as well, while in some projects i got the following error when `conn.Open()` is called:

```
"The 'PostgreSQL' provider is not registered on the local machine."
```

Up to now i did not success to find any preferences differences between the projects that works to the one those who not.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use OleDb instead of Npgsql?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use Npgsql, i have to try to make OleDB working.

Comment: I got the same issue, I search everywhere but could not find the solution. Any help, please?